# How to use org-export to export from a file in emacs

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs

I hava an input file name like `/path/to/orgfiles/file.org`

I have an output file name like `/path/to/mdfiles/file.md`

This two path have been set into two variables:

`inputfile`  = `"/path/to/orgfiles/file.org"`

`outputfile` = `"/path/to/mdfiles/file.md"`

Now I want to use `org-export-to-file` from `ox.el` to export inputfile to outputfile, how?

It seems that `org-export-to-file` can only export file from the current buffer, I couldn't find any function which can specified the INPUT file :(

I tried `org-publish` but it seems should be used when project involved, doesn't meet my need too.

Comment: I don't think you can explicitly tell `org` to take a certain file and export it to an arbitrary path. You can wrap export function to open your file in a buffer, export it, and then use the return value, which will be the name of the exported file to move it where you want your output to be.

Comment: Thanks @Drew , I've deleted the one on stackoverflow, first time ask a question, I'll keep it in mind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DoMiNeLa10 is correct. You have to create a function to do something like this. Here is one that is interactive. M-x export-file-md will prompt you for an input file and an output file name, and then export the org-file to the desired md-file name and open it. It does a little buffer management, e.g. closing the org file if it was not already open.

This isn't the only way to get this done, but it works fine as far as I can tell.

```
(defun export-file-md (org-file md-file)
  "Export ORG-FILE to MD-FILE."
  (interactive "f\nf")
  (unless (string= "org" (file-name-extension org-file))
    (error "INFILE must be an org file."))
  (unless (string= "md" (file-name-extension md-file))
    (error "OUTFILE must have an .md extension."))
  (let ((current-buffers (buffer-list))
    (tmp-buffer) 
    (open (find-buffer-visiting org-file))
    (org-file-buffer (find-file-noselect org-file)))
    (with-current-buffer org-file-buffer
      (with-current-buffer (setq tmp-buffer (org-org-export-as-org))
    (insert (format "#+EXPORT_FILE_NAME: %s\n" md-file))
    (org-open-file (org-md-export-to-markdown))))
    (kill-buffer tmp-buffer)
    (unless open (kill-buffer org-file-buffer))))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, `find-file-noseletct` and `with-current-buffer` is what I'm looking for. `(unless open (kill-buffer org-file-buffer))` this one makes it even better with closing the buffers which I don't need, your answer really inspired a lot!